# why angularjs dropdown('toggle') breaks angled-navbar?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, toggle, navbar

I'm testing angled-navbar:
http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/bcEsA

The problem is simple: when I try to programatically call a dropdown menu's 'toggle' action from where-ever, the dropdown cannot be opened anymore. Simple to reproduce:

1. run the codepen
2. set chrome console to the "codepen index.html" iframe
3. click on the left-most dropdown to expand it

Finally, while expanded, run in the console:

```
$('nav li[ng-repeat="menu in menus"]:first-child').dropdown('toggle');
```

Result: the dropdown closes, but now any click on it will not open it. This does not happen with "bare" bootstrap3 navbars, but it does happen with the angled-navbar impl.

any idea how to get the 'toggle' to work?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of headbanging, I finally found the solution: I need to call the 'toggle' action on the TOP LEVEL ANCHOR inside the dropdown menu - NOT on the dropdown menu 'li' tag itself:

```
$('nav li[ng-repeat="menu in menus"]:first-child > a').dropdown('toggle');
```

After the dropdown closes, it can be opened again! Narf.